# Reuse vertex attribute buffer as index buffer?

Tags: opengl

Can I use a VBO which I initialise like this:

```
GLuint bufferID;
glGenBuffers(1,&BufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,nBytes,indexData,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

as an index buffer, like this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferID);
/* ... set up vertex attributes, NOT using bufferID in the process ... */
glDrawElements(...);
```

I would like to use the buffer mostly as an attribute buffer and occasionally as an index buffer (but never at the same time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the GL which prevents you from doing such things, your code above is legal GL. You can bind every buffer to every buffer binding target (you can even bind the same buffer to different targets at the same time, so it is even OK if attributes and index data come from the same buffer). However, the GL implementation might do some optimizations based on the observed behavior of the application, so you might end up with sub-optimal performance if you suddenly change the usage of an existing buffer object with such an approach, or use it for two things at once.

**Update**

The [ARB_vertex_buffer_object extension spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt), which introduced the concept of buffer objects to OpenGL, mentions this topic in the "Issues" section:

> **Should this extension include support for allowing vertex indices to be stored in buffer objects?**
>
> RESOLVED: YES.  It is easily and cleanly added with just the
>           addition of a binding point for the index buffer object.  Since
>           our approach of overloading pointers works for any pointer in GL,
>           no additional APIs need be defined, unlike in the various
>           *_element_array extensions.
>
> Note that it is expected that implementations may have different
>           memory type requirements for efficient storage of indices and
>           vertices.  For example, some systems may prefer indices in AGP
>           memory and vertices in video memory, or vice versa; or, on
>           systems where DMA of index data is not supported, index data must
>           be stored in (cacheable) system memory for acceptable
>           performance.  As a result, applications are strongly urged to
>           put their models' vertex and index data in separate buffers, to
>           assist drivers in choosing the most efficient locations.

The reasoning that some implementations might prefer to keep index buffers in system RAM seems quite outdated, though.

Answer (score 2):

While completely legal, it's sometimes discouraged to have attribute data and index data in the same buffer. I suspect that this is mostly based on a paragraph in the spec document (e.g. page 49 of the OpenGL 3.3 spec, at the end of the section "2.9.7 Array Indices in Buffer Objects"):

> In some cases performance will be optimized by storing indices and array data in separate buffer objects, and by creating those buffer objects with the corresponding binding points.

While it seems plausible that it could be harmful to performance, I would be very interested to see benchmark results on actual platforms showing it. Attribute data and index data are used at the same time, and with the same access operations (CPU write, or blit from temporary storage, for filling the buffer with data, GPU read during rendering). So I can't think of a very good reason why they would need to be treated differently.

The only difference I can think of is that the index data is always read sequentially, while the attribute data is read out of order during indexed rendering. So it might be possible to apply different caching attributes for performance tuning the access in both cases.

Comment: That statement is probably a histroic remnant. The [ARB_vertex_buffer_object spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt) states "For example, some systems may prefer indices in AGP memory and vertices in video memory, or vice versa; or, on systems where DMA of index data is not supported, index data mustbe stored in (cacheable) system memory for acceptable performance."